# Escaping forward slashes with tr

Tags: perl, replace, escaping

I have a variable which contains `$var = "/var/run/hello.pid"`.

In order to replace that I need to change those `/` into `\/`. I was trying to use the Perl `tr` option like this:

```
$var =~ tr/\//\\\//;
```

But it takes only the first `\`, ending up with `$var = \var\run\hello.pid`.

The outcome I'm expecting is: `$var = \/var\/run\/hello.pid`

How can I achieve that with Perl? The `$var` variable can be generated randomly with those `/` (which means it's not a static variable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tr` translates character for character. Use

```
$var =~ s/\//\\\//g;
```

Note that Perl allows you to change the delimiter for readability.

```
$var =~ s{/}{\\/}g;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! worked like a charm!
i've been searching forever!

Comment: There's also `$var = quotemeta($var);`. That would escape all non-word characters. (So `/` and `.` in your example.)